# Non-rails application with RSpec, ActiveRecord and Factory Girl

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rspec, factory-bot

How to properly implement **RSpec**, **ActiveRecord** and **Factory Girl** in non-rails application. I also need that every test case would run on a clean database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ActiveRecord outside of Rails is a pretty common request, so there's plenty of blog posts and tutorials on getting it done, just [Google it](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=activerecord+~without+rails&aq=f&aqi=p-p1g-c1g-j1g-m2g-b5&aql=&oq=). Using it outside of Rails isn't very different from using it within Rails. The major difference is that you'll have to handle the things that Rails usually does for you, like creating the connection, and handling migrations.

RSpec was not designed specifically for Rails, so using that outside of Rails is a non-issue. Just follow the [standard tutorial](http://relishapp.com/rspec/file/twominutetutorial).

Same thing for factory_girl. Rails support was separated from factory_girl proper and moved into a separate gem, so using it without Rails is also simple. Its [standard README](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) should be sufficient.

For cleaning the database, use the [database_cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) gem.

Comment: "database_cleaner" was the missing bit. Thanks!

Comment: The Factory Girl README is not helpful at all for use outside of Rails.

Comment: My original post was almost a year ago. It's not surprising the README may have changed in that time. But the README *does* link to https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md which seems more than sufficient for getting started.